# Confusion about categorical viewpoint of normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

One way to define normal subgroups is as normal monos in $\mathsf{Grp}$. Another uses quotients by internal equivalence relations, which makes use (I think) of the fact $\mathsf{Grp}$ has effective equivalence relations - each equivalence relation is a the kernel pair of its coequalizer.

What's the theory linking these two definitions?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.  These are two different definitions, which happen to both coincide with normal subgroups when applied to the category of groups.

Comment: @EricWofsey okay, that's something I didn't understand. So it's pure coincidence in $\mathsf{Grp}$ that the objects by which you can quotient are exactly the ones which are (domains of) kernels?

Comment: Oh, I think I may have misinterpreted what you meant by "using quotients by internal equivalence relations".  In general, there is no reason to expect every quotient by an equivalence relation to be the quotient by a normal subobject (think about pointed sets).  However, it is true that if all equivalence relations are effective, then normal monomorphisms are the same as equivalence classes of zero for internal equivalence relations.

Comment: @EricWofsey what does equivalence class mean for an internal equivalence relation? What is meant by zero? Where can I find this result?

Comment: Well, what exactly is the second definition you are referencing in the question?  I'm assuming that that definition is exactly what I'm calling an "equivalence class of zero".

Comment: @EricWofsey well, assuming we only speak of groups, then I take it that by zero you mean the identity of the group. In that case, I understand what you mean. Still though, where can I find proof that if equivalence relations are effective, then normal monos are the same as equivalence classes of zero for internal equivalence relations?

Comment: May you tell me where I can find some resources on this subject "the categorical def of normal group" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me state the two definitions a bit more explicitly.  Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with a zero object.  For any objects $A$ and $B$, we let $0:A\to B$ denote the unique map which factors through a zero object.  Then:

1. A *normal monomorphism* is a map $i:A\to B$ such that there exists an object $C$ and a map $f:B\to C$ such that $i$ is the equalizer of $f$ and $0:B\to C$.
2. An *equivalence class of zero* (this is a term I just made up) is a map $i:A\to B$ such that there exists an equivalence relation $j:R\to B\times B$ such that $i$ is a pullback of $j$ by the map $(1,0):B\to B\times B$.

If $\mathcal{C}$ has pullbacks, then any normal monomorphism is an equivalence class of zero: suppose $f:B\to C$ is any map and let $j:R\to B\times B$ be the kernel pair of $f$.  Since $j$ is monic, an object $A$ with a map $i:A\to B$ and a map $A\to R$ such that 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> R\\
@VV{i}V @VV{j}V  \\
B @>{(1,0)}>> B\times B 
\end{CD}$$

commutes is the same as a map $i:A\to B$ such that $(1,0)\circ i=(i,0)$ factors through $j$.  But by the definition of $j$, $(i,0)$ factors through $j$ iff $f\circ i=f\circ 0=0=0\circ i$.  That is, such an $i$ is the same thing as a map which equalizes $f$ and $0$.  This shows that a map is a kernel of $f$ iff it is an equivalence class of zero for the equivalence relation $j$.

Conversely if all equivalence relations in $\mathcal{C}$ are effective, then every equivalence class of zero is normal.  Indeed, for any equivalence relation $j:R\to B\times B$, there is then some $f:B\to C$ such that $j$ is the kernel pair of $f$.  The argument above then shows that an equivalence class of zero of $j$ is a kernel of $f$.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much!

Comment: The proof is crystal clear but I'm still a little confused - normal subgroups of a group $G$ are the equivalence classes of the zero *element* (in additive convention). Here, the zero seems to be the zero object of $\mathsf{Grp}$... Could you explain what's going on?

Comment: The pullback $A$ as in the diagram above is the intersection of the sets $R\subset B\times B$ and $\{(b,0):b\in B\}\subset B\times B$, which is exactly the set of $b$ such that $b$ is $R$-equivalent to $0(b)=0$.  That is, instead of saying $b$ is equivalent to the zero element, we are saying $b$ is equivalent to the value of $b$ under the zero _map_.  But the zero map is just the map that always takes value zero, so these are the same.

Answer (score 2):

What links kernels and congruences? The [Mal'cev property](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mal'cev+variety).

In the setting of categories of algebraic structures with a constant, being a Mal'cev category essentially amounts to the existence of a subtraction operator. With that in mind, it is not surprising that kernels in Mal'cev categories contain the same information as congruences – after all, in $\mathbf{Grp}$, to quotient by a normal subgroup $N$ amounts to quotienting by $x \sim_N y$ where $x \sim_N y$ iff $x y^{-1} \in N$.